# Alias a database name within the query as to avoid dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have 4 distinct environments for one of our applications through our Dev to Prod pipeline, each having two databases.  Within these databases there are several queries referencing the other database. So for example we may have this:

```
select a.name, b.description 
FROM Database1.dbo.Names a 
INNER join Database2.dbo.Descriptions b on a.ID = b.ID;
```

Just an example, not an actual query from our system... but hopefully you get the point.  All four environments live on their own SQL servers so I can gracefully move code from bottom to top without any changes.

Now we're looking at possibly combining the bottom three environments on to the same SQL Server Instance (Prod will keep its own server), so all six databases will be on the same server together.  In doing this the database names will have a suffix of their type, so Database1_Dev and Database2_Dev for example.

Well there lies the issue, all queries using just Database1 and Database2 will now break, and if I do change them to use Database1_Dev and Database2_Dev at the lowest level I can't just move them up to the next level Database1_Sandbox and Database2_Sandbox without modifying the queries.

The options I'm looking at are requesting three SQL instances on this server - which I'm sure will get shot down - or changing the queries to use dynamic SQL where I can pass in the DB name as a variable.  I don't like either option.

Synonyms are the only thing I can think of that would allow a different name to be used, but this is going the wrong direction.  I don't need one DB to have multiple names, rather multiple databases to have the same name within the same context.  So like if in a procedure I could pass in the environment and I could alias Database1 to Database1_Sandbox just within the transaction or query. I don't think there is any way to do this, but I thought I'd ask.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I would strongly advise against putting different phases of the SDLC on the same environment in the first place, for a whole host of reasons I'm not going to get into in a comment (but you've already run head first into one of them). I don't precisely understand your comment about synonyms "going in the wrong direction". Synonyms are a possible solution here, but do note that you can't create a synonym just for a database. You would have to create a synonym for every referenced object.

Comment: Short answer - no. These things should have been discussed when designers chose to use multiple databases.

Comment: If you go the dynamic SQL route, don’t pass in the DB name as a variable, pass dynamic SQL without any database prefixes to `EXEC @exec @sql;` where `@exec = QUOTENAME(@db) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';`. See an example here: https://sqlblog.org/2021/11/08/x-to-y-database-z-1 The thing you pass to `@db` can come from a config table that has different values per env.

Comment: I didn’t read the whole thing because mobile and dinner but why not have the queries in views or stored procedures in each database? When you deploy a change, you just loop through all the databases and make the exact same alter in every DB.

Comment: A possible approach would be to put the code into SSDT, have the databases linked through database references with associated sqlcmd variables and have the database publish pipelines set the correct sqlcmd variable values for the environment being published to.

Comment: The easier solution, of course, is to use a different instance for each env, then you can have the same database names. Putting the dev databases on the same instance as other tiers kind of defeats the point of calling it a different env IMHO.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, that's an approach we tried many years ago (though not for the reasons OP wants to do it). The issue we always had with that approach was that some of the cross database queries were to schemas we did not control, and which could not be compiled. I had a conversation with Jamie Thomson about the feasibility of allowing dacpacs to have "hanging" references, some kind of "I assert this object will exist in the other database, so you don't need it to be compiled", but of course it was not an idea that was ever picked up.

Comment: @SamAlex - where do the queries come from? e.g. are they inside stored procs that live in sql files that you deploy?

Comment: I know it's not a solution but instead a "shoulda done it this way" comment, but for some time now I don't do any cross database. If things talk to each other they go into the same database and different schema. This helps database project work better, and allows much easier migration to Azure SQL.

Comment: Actually your idea _requesting three SQL instances on this server - which I'm sure will get shot down_ is the best solution. I don't see any downside to this. Why it should be shot down? It depends what reasoning they have in the first place. If it's to save hardware costs, then this is the perfect solution. If it's to save on sql instances for maintenance purposes, it might be an issue.